# "Bad CDB" message in VMware ESXi kernel logfile

Tags: vmware, esxi, scsi

I'm running the [VMware ESXi 5.5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_ESX) hypervisor and see a lot of error messages like below in its `/var/log/vmkernel.log` file:

```
<timestamp> cpu11:34032 opID=1ad4dfbe)<3>ata1.00: bad CDB len=16, scsi_op=0x9e, max=12
```

The SCSI operation with code `0x9e` is `SERVICE ACTION IN (16)`, which is 16-byte command. So, why does the server complains about the `max=12` limitation? What might be a reason to get these messages? What should I change to get rid of them?